# Copying style and formatting from one Word document to another

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting, styles

I was given two Word documents. One of them is pure text with tables and formulas, another is formatted with list of content, headers, footers and so on...

Now, I need to make my first document look exactly the same like the second one, is there any way to do it?

Tnx in advance

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use the "Organizer for styles and macros" feature which allows copying all or some styles from one document to another. [Copy styles and AutoText between documents or templates.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Copy-styles-and-AutoText-between-documents-or-templates-87C7DDE7-670C-43F4-A033-33309C86B61E)

Comment: Once you have the styles in Document 1, you'll need to apply them to the various parts of the document (e.g. apply Heading 1 style to the chapter headings)

Comment: The link to MS tutorial isn't helpful. In latest Word (2023), "Organizer..." is hiding with the Macros, so go there and switch tab to Styles. I suggest playing around with "prototype Word files" or in other "words", backup your original files before you go ahead.